# Where to find stock stochastic oscillator?

Tags: stocks, investing, stock-analysis, investment-strategies, equity

Any someone recommend a good site to find reliable stochastic oscillator graphs? I have looked up online and couldn't find any good reliable source. Stochastic Oscillator can be very useful to find the momentum of the stock which helps time your buy/sell actions.

Answer (score 2):

Any good charting software, many found online and many others you need to download. Alot of the online ones are through broker's platforms.

One which you need to download and has both a free and paid versions is incredible charts.

Comment: IncredibleCharts is good. The only disadvantage is they dont have current day data. Carries data only until the previous trading day.

Comment: The free version gets updated at night, I think around 9pm. The there are various paid versions, with the most costly being updated with 20 minute delayed data. It is probably not the best if you are day trading, but if you do longer term trading to investing where you might have a position open from a few days to years and place your orders after market close - then it is not too bad.

Comment: I found tradingView.com to have real-time (may be 20 mins delayed) Stochastic Oscillator and other technical indicators. They give one chart view free. If you need more then paid version is the way.